# Hide/show an element based on value of var

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide, show

I have these two menu items:-

```
<li role="presentation"><a class="logged" id="login_a" href="login.php" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Login"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i></a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a class="logged" id="logout_a" href="./includes/functions.php?contract_action=logout" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Logout"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i></a></li>
```

and I have this in my header (within script tags)

```
    var LoggedIN = "<?php echo $_SESSION['LoggedIN']; ?>";

    if (LoggedIN == 'yes') {
        $("#login_a").hide();
        $("#logout_a").show();
        // $(".logged").toggle();
        alert('User IS logged in!');
    }else{
        $("#logout_a").hide();
        $("#login_a").show();
        // $(".logged").toggle();
        alert('User is NOT logged in!');
    }
```

But the login menu item never hides (but the alert DOES show as user IS logged in) so I know the var IS getting the proper val AND that jquery can see that.

What am I doing wrong that the login menu item isn't hiding? (notice the .toggle one...I attempted this as well after seeing that in here as a possibility) I have been researching for two hours now with no joy.

And there won't be any kind of "click" option as I test that session var BEFORE ever displaying the page and if it isn't set I send the user to the login page...which takes them to a functions.php upon submit, which sends them back to the index.php upon logging in - which checks again if user is logged in and then presents them with the proper main page...all of THAT is working fine...I just can't get the darn menu to show/hide the correct buttons (the menu display as fontawesome images instead of text)

Comment: and the `else` part working? or not?? .. maybe you need to run your code in `$(document).ready(function(){  //code here  });`

Answer (score 1):

Went with using php to handle this...should have thought of that at the beginning but...occasionally go for fancy instead of simple/practical. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to test  what LoggedIN variable returning. Troubleshoot it!
I tried to replicate ur scenario here https://jsbin.com/hicefeh/edit?html,js,output try to change variable 'yes' or 'no'

```js
var LoggedIN = "yes"; // try to play here with yes or no

    if (LoggedIN == 'yes') {
        $("#login_a").hide();
        $("#logout_a").show();
        // $(".logged").toggle();
        alert('User IS logged in!');
    }else{
        $("#logout_a").hide();
        $("#login_a").show();
        // $(".logged").toggle();
        alert('User is NOT logged in!');
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
        <li role="presentation" id="login_a" ><a class="logged" href="login.php" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Login"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Login</a></li>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
        <li role="presentation" id="logout_a" ><a class="logged" href="./includes/functions.php?contract_action=logout" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Logout"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I indicated the alert is telling me exactly what it sees and I'm getting the alert that the user IS logged in so (looking at that part of the if statement) you can see it IS getting the proper value...just not doing anything else :/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to your javascript code is in the beginning of the html code. Due to that before loading html content for menu items javascript code execute. So its better you **put your javascript code below the html** content or put the jquery **document.ready**.